# Selecionar valores de outra tabela com mais de uma linha no WebSQL

Tags: sql, angularjs, array, ionic, websql

Estou usando Ionic + cordova + WebSql.
Tenho basicamente essas tabelas, parceiros e parceriroEnderecos. Na tabela de endereços pode conter mais de uma linha para cada parceiro.
Como faço para retorna esses valores?

Crio as tabelas assim:

```
databaseValues.setup();
  databaseValues.bancoDeDados.transaction(function(transacao) {
  transacao.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parceiroEnderecos (' +
    'parceiro_id INTEGER,' +
    'logradouro VARCHAR(200),' +
    'numero VARCHAR(10),' +
    'UNIQUE(parceiro_id, logradouro) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);', []
  );

  transacao.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parceiros (' +
    'id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,' +
    'nome_fantasia VARCHAR(300),' +
    'UNIQUE(id, nome_fantasia) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);', []
  );
});
```

No `ParceirosController` eu estou tentando fazer assim:

```
databaseValues.setup();
databaseValues.bancoDeDados.transaction(function(transacao) {
  transacao.executeSql('select * from parceiros', [], function(transacao, parceiros) {
    for (parceiro of parceiros.rows) {
      _enderecos = getParceiroEnderecos(parceiro.id);
      _parceiro = {
        id: parceiro.id,
        nome_fantasia: parceiro.nome_fantasia,
        avatar: parceiro.avatar,
        beneficio_qtd: parceiro.beneficio_qtd,
        beneficio_maior: parceiro.beneficio_maior,
        enderecos: _enderecos
      }
      $scope.parceiros.push(_parceiro);
    }
  });
});

getParceiroEnderecos = function(parceiro_id) {
  _enderecos = [];
  databaseValues.setup();
  databaseValues.bancoDeDados.transaction(function(transacao) {
    transacao.executeSql('select * from parceiroEnderecos where parceiro_id = ?;', [parceiro_id], function(transacao, enderecos) {
      _enderecos = [];

      for (endereco of enderecos.rows) {
        _endereco = {
          logradouro: endereco.logradouro,
          numero: endereco.numero
        }
        _enderecos.push(_endereco);
      }
    });
    return _enderecos;
  })
}
```

Só que como a `transacao` deve ser assíncrona, eu não consigo adicionar o endereço dentro do parceiro, algo assim:

```
parceiros = [
  {
    id: 1,
    nome_fantasia: 'empresa 1',
    enderecos: [
      {
        logradouro: 'Rua 1',
        numero: '123'
      },
      {
        logradouro: 'Rua 2',
        numero: '987'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve trabalhar com promessas de modo assíncrono da seguinte forma:

```
databaseValues.setup();
databaseValues.bancoDeDados.transaction(function(transacao) {
  transacao.executeSql('select * from parceiros', [], function(transacao, parceiros) {
    for (parceiro of parceiros.rows) {
      getParceiroEnderecos(parceiro.id).then(function(_enderecos) {
        _parceiro = {
          id: parceiro.id,
          nome_fantasia: parceiro.nome_fantasia,
          avatar: parceiro.avatar,
          beneficio_qtd: parceiro.beneficio_qtd,
          beneficio_maior: parceiro.beneficio_maior,
          enderecos: _enderecos
        }

        $scope.parceiros.push(_parceiro);
      })
    }
  });
});

getParceiroEnderecos = function(parceiro_id) {
  var promessa = $q.defer();

  _enderecos = [];
  databaseValues.setup();
  databaseValues.bancoDeDados.transaction(function(transacao) {
    transacao.executeSql('select * from parceiroEnderecos where parceiro_id = ?;', [parceiro_id], function(transacao, enderecos) {
      _enderecos = [];

      for (endereco of enderecos.rows) {
        _endereco = {
          logradouro: endereco.logradouro,
          numero: endereco.numero
        }
        _enderecos.push(_endereco);
      }
    });

    promessa.resolve(_enderecos);
  });

  return promessa.promise;
}
```

Neste caso utilize a biblioteca [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) para gerar a promessa a ser resolvida na função `getParceiroEnderecos`.

Comment: https://codepaste.net/xbphfd
No primeiro console.log só exibe um único id, no segundo console.log, todos ficam com o mesmo id